# Eliminación valores atipicos

Tags: python, pandas, funciones

he creado una función que saca los valores atípicos sobre la columna de un dataframe pasándole como parámetro el df y la columna:

```
import numpy as np
def outlier(df, col_name):
    q1 = np.percentile(np.array(df[col_name].tolist()), 25)
    q3 = np.percentile(np.array(df[col_name].tolist()), 75)
    IQR = q3 - q1
                      
    Q3 = q1+(3*IQR)
    Q1 = q3-(3*IQR)
    outlier_num = 0
                      
    for value in df[col_name].values.tolist():
        if (value < Q1) | (value > Q3):
            outlier_num +=1
    return Q1, Q3, outlier_num
```

El problema esta al intentar pasarle lo parametros:

```
df_covtype = df_covtype[(df_covtype['column_name'] > outlier(df_covtype, 'column_name')[0]) &
              (df_covtype['colum_name'] < outlier(df_covtype, 'column_name')[1])]
```

Me indica lo siguiente:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-e4962bb5c2b0> in <module>()
----> 1 df_covtype = df_covtype[(df_covtype['column_name'] > outlier(df_covtype, 'column_name')[0]) &
      2               (df_covtype['column_name'] < outlier(df_covtype, 'column_name')[1])]
      3 df_covtype.shape

1 frames
<ipython-input-119-f1e12f2fd893> in outlier(df, col_name)
      2 import numpy as np
      3 def outlier(df, col_name):
----> 4     q1 = np.percentile(np.array(df[col_name].tolist()), 25)
      5     q3 = np.percentile(np.array(df[col_name].tolist()), 75)
      6     IQR = q3 - q1

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Si alguien puede echarme una mano, lo agradeceria. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: intenta agregar values, df[col_name].values.tolist()

Comment: Copié y pegué tu código y no produce ningún error, no funciona, pero no produce errores, lo estoy probando con un `dataframe` de 3 columnas y 100 filas.

Comment: Buenas @HeytalePazguato, Lo he sacado de aqui, es de el mismo dataset. Si bajas, debajo deoutlier_function, es lo que estoy intentando hacer  https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-forest-cover-types-with-the-machine-learning-workflow-1f6f049bf4df

Comment: Ya veo, copié y pegué el de la página y si funciona correctamente, vi que en tu caso tienes mal los `Q3` (Debe ser `Q3 = q3+(3*IQR)`) y `Q1` (Debe ser `Q1 = q1-(3*IQR)`) y el `for` tiene `values` de más (Debe ser `for value in df[col_name].tolist():`) Al copiar, pegar y refactorizar (Renombrar variables) es importante revisar 2 ó 3 veces cada línea. Cambiando eso ya funciona

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, he quitado el .values, porque era lo que estaba mal, si te fijas bien en el ejemplo veras que el Q3 y el Q1 estan bien. Igualmente me da error al hacer el q1 que es donde dice que no es un atributo tolist

Comment: No, `Q3` es el límite superior que está directamente relacionado a `q3` que es el tercer quantile...

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, tiene razón, lo había leído yo mal. Y viendo que el ejemplo que te pase y lo que tengo yo por que me puede dar el error del tolist, me gustaría aprovechar igual que el ejemplo la función ya que me parece que simplificas y pones menos codigo, aunque sea mas complejo

Comment: Como te comenté, copie y pegué tu código y a mi no me devuelve ningún error, no funciona, pero no devuelve error. Luego lo modifiqué tal como el de la página que agregaste y funciona correctamente. ¿Sería posible que hayas arreglado el error al publicar tu pregunta? El `for` también está mal pero el error lo devuelve donde calculas `q1`  tal vez algo con tus datos. Intenta hacerlo con el `dataframe` de ejemplo que puse en mi respuesta y funciona correctamente después de hacer los cambios que comenté anteriormente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay una forma un poco más sencilla de hacer lo que buscas utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) y [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Primero voy a generar un `dataframe` para el ejemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Esto devuelve un `dataframe` de 3 columnas y 100 filas con valores aleatorios

Ahora obtenemos los límites bajo y alto para detectar los valores atípicos

```
low = 0.25
high = 0.75

quant_df  = df.quantile([low, high])
```

Esto nos entregará un `dataframe` como el siguiente:

```
        A           B           C
0.25    -0.675637   -0.552684   -0.823368
0.75    0.754698    0.863303    0.343633
```

Indicando los límites para cada columna

Por último utilizamos `apply()` en el `dataframe` original utilizando los límites obtenidos en el `dataframe` anterior

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[(x > quant_df.loc[low,x.name]) & (x < quant_df.loc[high,x.name])], axis=0)
```

**Nota:** Si deseas incluir los límites entonces debes usar `>=` y `<=` respectivamente, en el ejemplo anterior los límites están excluidos

**Nota 2:** Si deseas excluir alguna columna debes hacerlo antes de aplicar los límites, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
filt_df = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Columna_excluida']
```

Y en este caso haríamos el `apply` en `filt_df` en lugar del `dataframe` original

Por último, si deseas eliminar las filas que contengan cualquier `NaN` ocacionado por el `apply` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
#Numpy lo utilizo para generar el dataframe ejemplo
import numpy as np

#Gererar el dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

low = 0.25
high = 0.75

quant_df  = df.quantile([low, high])

df = df.apply(lambda x: x[(x > quant_df.loc[low,x.name]) & (x < quant_df.loc[high,x.name])], axis=0)

#Opcional para eliminar filas con NaN en cualquier columna
df = df.dropna(inplace=True)
```