# ¿Cómo verificar correctamente si hay al menos un valor atípico en una serie de precios OHLC en Python? Relacionado con Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, estadística, función-personalizada

Tengo una inquietud relacionada con algo de estadística y programación, sucede que tengo una variablle llamada `df_trading_pair` la cual contiene una serie de precios registrados en el marco de tiempo de 30m (30 minutos):

```
    Start Date              Open Price  High Price  Low Price   Close Price  End Date
0   2022-07-09 22:30:00.000 0.04805     0.04806     0.0476      0.04775      2022-07-09 22:59:59.999
1   2022-07-09 23:00:00.000 0.04773     0.04776     0.0476      0.04764      2022-07-09 23:29:59.999
2   2022-07-09 23:30:00.000 0.04762     0.04776     0.04752     0.04769      2022-07-09 23:59:59.999
3   2022-07-10 00:00:00.000 0.04771     0.04789     0.04687     0.047        2022-07-10 00:29:59.999
4   2022-07-10 00:30:00.000 0.047       0.04708     0.04663     0.04671      2022-07-10 00:59:59.999
5   2022-07-10 01:00:00.000 0.0467      0.04681     0.04648     0.04671      2022-07-10 01:29:59.999
6   2022-07-10 01:30:00.000 0.04671     0.04698     0.04656     0.0467       2022-07-10 01:59:59.999
7   2022-07-10 02:00:00.000 0.04657     0.04671     0.04623     0.04625      2022-07-10 02:29:59.999
8   2022-07-10 02:30:00.000 0.04625     0.04629     0.04603     0.04624      2022-07-10 02:59:59.999
9   2022-07-10 03:00:00.000 0.04622     0.04623     0.04584     0.04591      2022-07-10 03:29:59.999
10  2022-07-10 03:30:00.000 0.04591     0.04677     0.04576     0.04586      2022-07-10 03:59:59.999
11  2022-07-10 04:00:00.000 0.04581     0.0461      0.04549     0.04592      2022-07-10 04:29:59.999
12  2022-07-10 04:30:00.000 0.04595     0.04614     0.04575     0.04596      2022-07-10 04:59:59.999
13  2022-07-10 05:00:00.000 0.04593     0.0461      0.04574     0.04596      2022-07-10 05:29:59.999
14  2022-07-10 05:30:00.000 0.04601     0.04614     0.04582     0.0459       2022-07-10 05:59:59.999
15  2022-07-10 06:00:00.000 0.04589     0.04591     0.04553     0.04571      2022-07-10 06:29:59.999
16  2022-07-10 06:30:00.000 0.04563     0.04586     0.04532     0.04552      2022-07-10 06:59:59.999
17  2022-07-10 07:00:00.000 0.04546     0.04571     0.04543     0.04563      2022-07-10 07:29:59.999
18  2022-07-10 07:30:00.000 0.04559     0.04592     0.04559     0.04579      2022-07-10 07:59:59.999
19  2022-07-10 08:00:00.000 0.04579     0.04611     0.04579     0.04598      2022-07-10 08:29:59.999
20  2022-07-10 08:30:00.000 0.04601     0.0461      0.04572     0.04576      2022-07-10 08:59:59.999
21  2022-07-10 09:00:00.000 0.04576     0.04587     0.04562     0.04572      2022-07-10 09:29:59.999
22  2022-07-10 09:30:00.000 0.04573     0.04589     0.043       0.0456       2022-07-10 09:59:59.999
23  2022-07-10 10:00:00.000 0.04559     0.04584     0.04555     0.04562      2022-07-10 10:29:59.999
24  2022-07-10 10:30:00.000 0.04567     0.04581     0.04552     0.04555      2022-07-10 10:59:59.999
25  2022-07-10 11:00:00.000 0.04561     0.04588     0.04548     0.04549      2022-07-10 11:29:59.999
26  2022-07-10 11:30:00.000 0.0455      0.04564     0.04532     0.04553      2022-07-10 11:59:59.999
27  2022-07-10 12:00:00.000 0.04558     0.04568     0.04549     0.04563      2022-07-10 12:29:59.999
28  2022-07-10 12:30:00.000 0.04563     0.04565     0.04555     0.04557      2022-07-10 12:59:59.999
29  2022-07-10 13:00:00.000 0.04568     0.04578     0.04534     0.04542      2022-07-10 13:29:59.999
30  2022-07-10 13:30:00.000 0.04543     0.04669     0.0447      0.04483      2022-07-10 13:59:59.999
31  2022-07-10 14:00:00.000 0.04481     0.04481     0.04434     0.04448      2022-07-10 14:29:59.999
32  2022-07-10 14:30:00.000 0.04449     0.04453     0.04421     0.04443      2022-07-10 14:59:59.999
33  2022-07-10 15:00:00.000 0.04442     0.0448      0.04436     0.04447      2022-07-10 15:29:59.999
34  2022-07-10 15:30:00.000 0.04441     0.04465     0.04438     0.0446       2022-07-10 15:59:59.999
35  2022-07-10 16:00:00.000 0.04463     0.04464     0.04419     0.04432      2022-07-10 16:29:59.999
36  2022-07-10 16:30:00.000 0.04434     0.04474     0.0443      0.04452      2022-07-10 16:59:59.999
37  2022-07-10 17:00:00.000 0.04452     0.04482     0.04451     0.0448       2022-07-10 17:29:59.999
38  2022-07-10 17:30:00.000 0.0448      0.04499     0.04475     0.04497      2022-07-10 17:59:59.999
39  2022-07-10 18:00:00.000 0.04488     0.045       0.04472     0.04499      2022-07-10 18:29:59.999
40  2022-07-10 18:30:00.000 0.04502     0.04539     0.04483     0.04535      2022-07-10 18:59:59.999
41  2022-07-10 19:00:00.000 0.04532     0.04559     0.04497     0.04509      2022-07-10 19:29:59.999
42  2022-07-10 19:30:00.000 0.0451      0.04531     0.04501     0.04514      2022-07-10 19:59:59.999
43  2022-07-10 20:00:00.000 0.04514     0.04528     0.04508     0.04525      2022-07-10 20:29:59.999
44  2022-07-10 20:30:00.000 0.04515     0.0452      0.04509     0.04517      2022-07-10 20:59:59.999
45  2022-07-10 21:00:00.000 0.04522     0.04546     0.04513     0.04514      2022-07-10 21:29:59.999
46  2022-07-10 21:30:00.000 0.04519     0.04534     0.04513     0.04534      2022-07-10 21:59:59.999
47  2022-07-10 22:00:00.000 0.04534     0.04534     0.04474     0.0449       2022-07-10 22:29:59.999
48  2022-07-10 22:30:00.000 0.0448      0.04507     0.04475     0.04482      2022-07-10 22:59:59.999
49  2022-07-10 23:00:00.000 0.04481     0.04481     0.04443     0.04455      2022-07-10 23:29:59.999
50  2022-07-10 23:30:00.000 0.04451     0.04451     0.04428     0.04442      2022-07-10 23:59:59.999
51  2022-07-11 00:00:00.000 0.04442     0.04442     0.04374     0.04382      2022-07-11 00:29:59.999
52  2022-07-11 00:30:00.000 0.0438      0.04413     0.04368     0.04399      2022-07-11 00:59:59.999
53  2022-07-11 01:00:00.000 0.04395     0.04402     0.04319     0.04342      2022-07-11 01:29:59.999
54  2022-07-11 01:30:00.000 0.04343     0.04348     0.04323     0.04329      2022-07-11 01:59:59.999
55  2022-07-11 02:00:00.000 0.04333     0.04338     0.04314     0.04331      2022-07-11 02:29:59.999
56  2022-07-11 02:30:00.000 0.04332     0.04332     0.04312     0.04318      2022-07-11 02:59:59.999
57  2022-07-11 03:00:00.000 0.04317     0.04337     0.04309     0.04322      2022-07-11 03:29:59.999
58  2022-07-11 03:30:00.000 0.04322     0.04327     0.04299     0.04307      2022-07-11 03:59:59.999
59  2022-07-11 04:00:00.000 0.04305     0.04313     0.04273     0.0428       2022-07-11 04:29:59.999
```

Una vez graficada dicha serie de precios usando las siguientes líneas de código:

```
import finplot as fplt
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df_trading_pair[['Start Date', 'Open Price', 'Close Price', 'High Price', 'Low Price']]).colors.update(dict(bull_frame='#26a69a', bull_body='#26a69a', bull_shadow='#26a69a'))
fplt.show()
```

Se obtiene su gráfica de velas japonesas correspondiente:

[image: trading_chart]

Entonces, al mirar fijamente esta gráfica, se evidencia que existe un valor atípico, el cual es `0.043` y este puede ser llamado al ejecutar `df_trading_pair['Low Price'].iat[22]` en este caso.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo podría identificar eso con algunas líneas de código?

Estaba pensando en considerar la siguiente fórmula:

> **In [2]:** `(df_trading_pair["Close Price"]-df_trading_pair["Low Price"])/df_trading_pair["Low Price"]*100`

La cual al ejecutarse devuelve la siguiente salida:

```
0     0.315126
1     0.084034
2     0.357744
3     0.277363
4     0.171563
5     0.494836
6     0.300687
7     0.043262
8     0.456224
9     0.152705
10    0.218531
11    0.945263
12    0.459016
13    0.480979
14    0.174596
15    0.395344
16    0.441306
17    0.440238
18    0.438693
19    0.414938
20    0.087489
21    0.219202
22    6.046512
23    0.153677
24    0.065905
25    0.021988
26    0.463372
27    0.307760
28    0.043908
29    0.176445
30    0.290828
31    0.315742
32    0.497625
33    0.247971
34    0.495719
35    0.294184
36    0.496614
37    0.651539
38    0.491620
39    0.603757
40    1.159938
41    0.266845
42    0.288825
43    0.377107
44    0.177423
45    0.022158
46    0.465322
47    0.357622
48    0.156425
49    0.270088
50    0.316170
51    0.182899
52    0.709707
53    0.532531
54    0.138793
55    0.394066
56    0.139147
57    0.301694
58    0.186090
59    0.163819
dtype: float64
```

Según dicha información, yo infiero que los valores de arriba deberían moverse entre `0.021987` a `1.159938` y que `6.046512` es el valor atípico, pero no soy un experto en estadística y no sé cómo debería plantear la lógica de esto en código de Python, ¿puedo obtener algo de ayuda aquí?

Comment: Buen día, por favor revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/536209/171630) que le di a otro usuario con una pregunta similar (Ahí se muestra como eliminar valores atípicos en un `dataframe`). En estadística, es común eliminar valores que sean menores al 25% y mayores al 75%. [Lectura recomendada](https://support.minitab.com/es-mx/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/statistics/basic-statistics/supporting-topics/data-concepts/identifying-outliers/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a **@HeytalePazguato** logré entender y crear una solución ajustada a mi caso, primero se define la función `outlier` (Sacada de [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536196/eliminaci%C3%B3n-valores-atipicos/))

```
def outlier(df, col_name):
    q1 = np.percentile(np.array(df[col_name].tolist()), 25)
    q3 = np.percentile(np.array(df[col_name].tolist()), 75)
    IQR = q3 - q1
                      
    Q3 = q1+(3*IQR)
    Q1 = q3-(3*IQR)
    outlier_num = 0
                      
    for value in df[col_name].values.tolist():
        if (value < Q1) | (value > Q3):
            print(f'the outlier value is {value}')
            outlier_num +=1
    return Q1, Q3, outlier_num
```

Luego se crea una sub dataframe llamada `df_open_low_price_range` que guardará la serie de datos que se desea analizar y comprobar que tenga valores atípicos o no (*me di cuenta que para mi caso particular esta es la verdadera fórmula a usar para obtener el dato atípico*):

```
df_open_low_price_range = pd.DataFrame((df_trading_pair["Open Price"]-df_trading_pair["Low Price"])/df_trading_pair["Low Price"]*100, columns= ["Open Low Price Range"])
```

Después se ejecuta la función `outlier` y se almacena su tupla en la variable `the_outlier`:

```
the_outlier = outlier(df_open_low_price_range, 'Open Low Price Range')
```

Finalmente se agregan dos condicionales para concluir la labor:

```
if the_outlier[2] == 0:
   print("Esta serie de datos NO tiene valores atípicos")

elif the_outlier[2] >= 1:
   print("Esta serie de datos SI tiene valores atípicos")
```